# Spatial Mapping of assets inside a building using ARKit

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, indoor-positioning-system

I know my question sounds very broad but that's the nature of the problem statement I am working on. I am not looking for code samples (unless it helps explain the solution) but an explanation more from a technology perspective and challenges therein.

My company has indoor positioning figured out from a 3rd party vendor using beacons. Accuracy is about 3-5m which is acceptable for the kind of use case we have. What we also want to try and do is map few fixed assets in 3D space based on their 2D position (x,y) information that we receive from the indoor positioning solution. We would like to use ARKit for doing the spatial mapping of these assets in AR view. What we have with us in order to realise a solution like this is real-time position information of the user in (x, y), real-time azimuth as observed on the user's device hence giving the user's bearing and as stated earlier the position information in (x, y) of the fixed assets in the building.

I would like to know, for doing spatial mapping of these assets in 3D space (assuming a fixed elevation for these assets), would the data that we have suffice? What else does ARKit need in order to accurately map these assets in AR view? I have done some reading on AR sessions and world tracking configurations in ARKit and not very sure if we should be using world alignment of gravity or gravity/heading? Should we be converting the x, y coordinates as received from the indoor positioning software to lat, long?

Any pointers towards the correct approach would be much appreciated. And sorry again if the questions sound too broad, I will try to be as specific in my responses to your questions if need be.

Thanks,

Myra

Comment: I am confused by your question.  
 - "is map few fixed assets" 
 - "for doing spatial mapping" 
 - "accurately map these assets in AR" 
What do you mean by mapping in this case?

What would you expect to see on screen exactly?

Comment: By mapping I meant overlaying the assets on the camera view in 3D space as per their location, position, direction within the building.

Comment: Try https://6d.ai